# Default trust relationship between domains in a forest?

Tags: active-directory

Can somebody clarify that all domains, child domains, subsubdomain all trust each other two way if in the same forest by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved.

everything in the same forest has a default two way transitive trust